# using the facebook javascript sdk with a web worker

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, web-worker

I have a Facebook application that needs to query a lot of data from the Graph API. I can currently pull all of the data using the Facebook javascript-sdk, however the user has to wait for facebook to return the query every time (.5-1.0 seconds). I wanted to put this functionality in a javascript web worker so that it will continuously run in the background pulling the data and storing it in a javascript array for when the user needs it.

I am new to javascript web workers but I know that they have limitations that prevent them from accessing the following:

- The DOM (it's not thread-safe)
- The window object
- The document object
- The parent object

Do these limitations prevent me from being able to load the Facebook Javascript-SDK in my web worker and use it to make calls?

Also, I tried using: `importScripts("http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js");` as an alternative way to load the script it gave me a "Uncaught Undefined" Error.

Currently I have my web worker passing data to and from my page (including the user access token) but I do not know how to make api calls without the SDK.

Note: My application is using only javascript, has no database and no back end server code (php, ruby, etc).  I need to keep it this way.

Answer (score 1):

When you connect to the Facebook SDK you should receive an accessToken in the response.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  }
});
```

Send this accessToken to your Web Worker:

```
var myWorker = new Worker(url);
myWorker.sendMessage({accessToken:accessToken});
```

Now you can use XMLHttpRequest and the Facebook graph api (inside the web worker):

```
//inside your worker
onmessage = function (oEvent) {
var accessToken = oEvent.data.accessToken;
if(accessToken){
    function loaded(){
      var fbResponse = this.responseText;
      postMessage({fbData: fbResponse});
    }

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = loaded;
    if (xhr != null) {
        xhr.open('get', 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?type=normal&method=GET&access_token='+accessToken, true);
        xhr.send();
    }else {
        postMessage({error: 'XHR not supported'});
    }
}else{
    postMessage({error: 'No access token'});
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js -s | grep "document" -q && echo "Nope."
```

Just so you don't have to actually execute this: it will print "Nope."

Sorry.

That said: you should check out the `async` flag on `XMLHttpRequest.open`.